# Storing data on the least 3 significant bit of an 8 bit image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Can anybody help me to store the name, city and phone no. on the least 3 significant bits of an 8 bit image. I want to display the image and then extract store data and print it.

Comment: Are you looking to do this like metadata, or like steganography?

Comment: yes looking to do this like metadata. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought about it some more, and I really don't think what you're asking for is metadata. Setting the metadata is just easier than what you seem to be actually asking for.

Anyway, if all you really want to do is set the metadata, this can be done by rewritting the image using imwrite, with the 'Comment' parameter set. Look up MATLAB's imwrite for more information on this.

If instead what you want is steganography, then you need to use dec2bin to translate the string into binary data. Then go through this bitstring bit by bit, and OR it with the least significant bits of the image (apply dec2bin to it as well). You'll need to covnert the bitstring back to uint8 since the bitstrings are chars. Also, you can't save it in a lossy format, so no jpegs.

This solution is fairly complicated and requires careful coding. More than I feel like writing here. Especially when you're trying to read it all back (remember that the size of the image and the length of the string you want to hide will vary from image to image, and your de-encrypter will need to be able to handle this).

Answer (score 1):

All of the things you want to do here are very simple.  Rather then writing the code for you I suggest you learn how to use matlab. If you are pressed for time recruit someone to help you.

Also I highly suggest you read this article: http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2006/10/17/the-story-behind-the-matlab-default-image/